# MKMarkerAnnotationView don't show on iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mapkit

On older phones (iPhone 7, 8) the `MKMarkerAnnotationView` that are created for a `MKMapSnapshotter` show correctly on the map. Only on the iPhone X and above are they not showing. I can't tell what the issue may be. Here is the code that creates the snapshot

```
static func generateMap(coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D], id: String){

  var annotationViews = [MKMarkerAnnotationView]()
  let startCoord = coordinates.first!
  let endCoord = coordinates.last!

  ///create mapmarker
  func createMapMarkerAnnotation(text: String, coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D, color: UIColor) -> MKMarkerAnnotationView{
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = coordinates

        let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "marker")
        annotationView.glyphText = text
        annotationView.glyphTintColor = .white
        annotationView.markerTintColor = color
        annotationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        annotationView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        return annotationView
    }

   //CREATE MARKERS
   annotationViews.append(createMapMarkerAnnotation(text: "A", coordinates: startCoord, color: Constants.primaryGreen))
   annotationViews.append(createMapMarkerAnnotation(text: "B", coordinates: endCoord, color: Constants.primaryGreen))

  let snapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)
    snapshotter.start { (snapshot: MKMapSnapshotter.Snapshot?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        guard error == nil, let snapshot = snapshot else { return }

        let image = snapshot.image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, true, image.scale);
        image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero) //image into context


        /// get the context for CoreGraphics
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        ///draw markers
        for view in annotationViews {
            let point: CGPoint = snapshot.point(for: view.annotation!.coordinate)
            view.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(x: point.x - view.bounds.size.width / 2, y: point.y - view.bounds.size.height, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }

        let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        if let img = finalImage {
            let data: Data? = img.pngData()
            let content = data?.base64EncodedString()

            //write to db
            _ = DbTrips.shareInstance.updateTripMap(id: id, map: content!)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone have any idea of what may be causing them to not appear on newer phones?

Thanks ^.^

Comment: What you’re trying to do is wrong. A map snapshot shows Apple’s map, not your map. If your goal is to show annotations, show a MKMapView, not a snapshot.

Comment: Micah, I’ve tried your code above and while you could tidy up a few minor things (e.g. I’d use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` rather than the old `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` API), it seems to work fine. See https://i.imgur.com/g3oxeZw.png for example I generated. We need a reproducible example of your problem. Here is my rendition that generated that image: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/982e18b8b398690914180cd1ae28fce4

Comment: Probably needless to say, I tested this on iPhone XS Max running iOS 13.2, and it worked fine. I’d suggest confirming that your annotation view coordinates are what you think they should be, that the resulting `CGRect` that you supply to `drawHierarchy` is what you think it should be, etc. But I cannot reproduce this behavior on the basis of what was supplied and we need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks Rob for thoroughly checking through. I'll double check the coordinates but since it works fine for 7/8 and not X with 13.2, it may be about the pattern you talk about.  Older phones do fine with it but X may be a bit finicky. If you could find that link again and post it, I'd be most interested in seeing it.

Comment: The technique outlined in this question is correct, and is precisely the pattern outlined in WWDC 2013 [Putting Map Kit in Perspective](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/309/?time=2086). The only difference is that they used the `image` of `MKPinAnnotationView`, but that doesn’t work with `MKMarkerAnnotationView`, and this uses `drawHierarchy` which seems perfectly appropriate fix.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the info. I'll look over the pattern outlined and may try what they have to see if it is more reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution to this is that when generating the map and views, it needs to happen when the app is active. For new phones attempts to generate the views in the background wouldn't work. On older phones it would. Why? I don't know. So, what needs to happen is that the map generation needs to happen only when the app is active. Doing this results in consistent generation across all devices.

I've been unsuccessful in finding again where this is is posted in the SDK docs but that is where I found the solution.